# How to solve error Number: 1048 Column 'photo_pict' cannot be null?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I got this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'photo_pict' cannot be null

    INSERT INTO `tester` (`photo_pict`, `press_pict`, `name_pict`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/pretest/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

I'm using CodeIgniter and I'm a beginner programmer.

I was making a register form, all I have to do is just saving the input from the register form to the database. But every data has been saved to database except the data for saving photo to the database.

Code show here

Model :

```
function insert($data){
     $data = array(
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'birthDate' => $data['birthDate'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'posisi' => $data['posisi'],
        'media_name' => $data['media_name'],
        'media_region' => $data['media_region'],
        'media_ctgry' => $data['media_ctgry'],
        'company_addrss' => $data['company_addrss'],
        'website' => $data['website'],
        'editor_email' => $data['editor_email'],
        'office_phone' => $data['office_phone'],
        'office_fax' => $data['office_fax'],
        'personal_email' => $data['personal_email'],
        'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
        'working_email' => $data['working_email']
    );
    $this->db->insert('tester', $data);
}

    function upload($data){
     $gambar = array(
    'photo_pict'=> $data['photo_pict'],
    'press_pict'=> $data['press_pict'],
    'name_pict'=> $data['name_pict']
    );
    $this->db->insert('tester', $gambar);
}

    function proses_regist(){
    return $this->db->insert('tester', $data);
    }
}
```

My Controller :

```
public function __construct(){
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->model("Model_regist");
    $this->load->helper(array('url','form'));
}

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('home');
}

function register(){
    $gambar = array(
    'press_pict'=>$this->upload->data("photo_pict"),
    'photo_pict'=>$this->upload->data("press_pict"),
    'name_pict'=>$this->upload->data("name_pict")
    );

    $data = array(
        'first_name' => $this->input->post("first_name"),
        'last_name' => $this->input->post("last_name"),
        'birthDate' => $this->input->post("birthDate"),
        'gender' => $this->input->post("gender"),
        'posisi' => $this->input->post("posisi"),
        'media_name' => $this->input->post("media_name"),
        'media_region' => $this->input->post("media_region"),
        'media_ctgry' => $this->input->post("media_ctgry"),
        'company_addrss' => $this->input->post("company_addrss"),
        'website' => $this->input->post("website"),
        'editor_email' => $this->input->post("editor_email"),
        'office_phone' => $this->input->post("office_phone"),
        'office_fax' => $this->input->post("office_fax"),
        'personal_email' => $this->input->post("personal_email"),
        'phone_number' => $this->input->post("phone_number"),
        'working_email' => $this->input->post("working_email")
);
    $this->Model_regist->insert($data);
    $this->Model_regist->upload($gambar);
    $this->index();
}

private function uploadImage(){
    $config['upload_path']          = './gambar/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['file_name']            = $this->product_id;
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;
    $config['overwrite']             = true;
    $nama_file                   = "gambar_".time();
    $config['file_name']             = $nama_file;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

if( ! $this->upload->do_upload('berkas')){
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
}else{
    $this->upload->data();
}
    $this->Model_regist->upload($gambar);
    $this->Model_regist->insert($data);
    $this->index();

}
```

I expect the photo that has been chosen can be saved in the database and can be saved in the file that I have made before. The file name is gambar.

Comment: The reason appears to be that you have not defined $gambar in your uploadImage function so it's going to be all NULL's. What is your reasoning for performing two separate (different) inserts into the table called tester? Also in the next line, $data is not defined either. Your function called register looks 'ok' so compare it to that one. Am I right in thinking you are attempting to insert a new user details, then later add in the image details? If that is the case you would need to perform an update on the ID you got from the initial insert for the new  profile. Too much to go over here.

Comment: Hmm I see.. Thanks for the advice.. I will try to fix it now.. If I find another error, I will ask again..